# Create an array based on a specific string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a problem, I would like to ask for this string:

`[NAME: abc] [EMAIL: email@gm.com] [TIMEFRAME: 3 weeks] [BUDGET: 1000 dollars] [MESSAGE: bla bla bla]`

Replace it with an array in the form:

```
array(
        'NAME'      => 'abc',
        'EMAIL'     => 'email@gm.com',
        'TIMEFRAME' => '3 weeks',
        'BUDGET'    => '1000 dollars',
        'MESSAGE'   => 'bla bla bla' );
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
$content = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', '[NAME: abc] [EMAIL: email@gm.com] [TIMEFRAME: 3 weeks] [BUDGET: 1000 dollars] [MESSAGE: bla bla bla]');
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]+\:/', $content, $inputs);
```

I managed to pull out the "keys", but I do not know how to pull out their "values". Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help and I apologize for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
'~\[(\w+):\s*([^][]*)]~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9WxhD2/1/).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: 1+ letters, digits or `_`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+whitespaces
- `([^][]*)` - Group 2: 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/I9bdTe):

```
$s = "[NAME: abc] [EMAIL: cde] [TIMEFRAME: efg] [BUDGET: hij] [MESSAGE: klm]";
if (preg_match_all('~\[(\w+):\s*([^][]*)]~', $s, $m)) {
    array_shift($m); // Removes whole match values from array
    print_r(array_combine($m[0], $m[1])); // Build the result with keys (Group 1) and values (Group 2)
}
```