# Creating a array based on an expert level string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I have a string divided based on the answers from this [create an array based on a specific string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920558/create-an-array-based-on-a-specific-string-in-php). I would like to extend it a bit:

```
$content = '
    [2130701433] [NAME: aaa] [VALUE: aaa] [EXPIRE: 1 second] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701433] [NAME: bbb] [VALUE: bbb] [EXPIRE: 2 minute] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701433] [NAME: ccc] [VALUE: ccc] [EXPIRE: 3 hours] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]

    [2130701434] [NAME: aaa] [VALUE: aaa] [EXPIRE: 1 second] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701434] [NAME: bbb] [VALUE: bbb] [EXPIRE: 2 minute] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701434] [NAME: ccc] [VALUE: ccc] [EXPIRE: 3 hours] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]

    [2130701435] [NAME: aaa] [VALUE: aaa] [EXPIRE: 1 second] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701435] [NAME: bbb] [VALUE: bbb] [EXPIRE: 2 minute] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701435] [NAME: ccc] [VALUE: ccc] [EXPIRE: 3 hours] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]';
```

And divide it as follows:

```
$content = array(
    '2130701433' => array(
        'NAME'      => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'VALUE'     => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'EXPIRE'    => ['1 second', '2 minute', '3 hours'],
        'CREATED'   => ['Y:m:d H:i:s', 'Y:m:d H:i:s', 'Y:m:d H:i:s']
    ),

    '2130701434' => array(
        'NAME'      => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'VALUE'     => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'EXPIRE'    => ['1 second', '2 minute', '3 hours'],
        'CREATED'   => ['Y:m:d H:i:s', 'Y:m:d H:i:s', 'Y:m:d H:i:s']
    ),

    '2130701435' => array(
        'NAME'      => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'VALUE'     => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'EXPIRE'    => ['1 second', '2 minute', '3 hours'],
        'CREATED'   => ['Y:m:d H:i:s', 'Y:m:d H:i:s', 'Y:m:d H:i:s']
    ),
);
```

Current code:

```
if(preg_match_all('~\[(\w+):\s*([^][]*)]~', $content, $matches)){
    array_shift($matches);
    array_combine($matches[0], $matches[1]);
}
```

Is this solution real and is it worth it?

Thank you in advance for your help and I apologize for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\G` "continue" metacharacter is the hero of this pattern.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html  This makes the pattern infinitely extensible in case you want to add more bracketed key-value pairs in the future.

After the `id` number is found, the pattern seeks a very predictable bracketed structure and doesn't stop matching until the string breaks the continuation pattern.

Once the `$matches` array is generated, you only need to isolate which matches are the `id` numbers.  Because the `id` set of matches doesn't have a `[2]` element, check for `isset($item[2])` -- if it doesn't exist, store the `id` located at `$item[1]`, otherwise store the key-value pair.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0bf63dc74da297c045bf18c1cf4b453f92c4326)) ([Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9exRc/1))

```
$content = '
    [2130701433] [NAME: aaa] [VALUE: aaa] [EXPIRE: 1 second] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701433] [NAME: bbb] [VALUE: bbb] [EXPIRE: 2 minute] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701433] [NAME: ccc] [VALUE: ccc] [EXPIRE: 3 hours] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]

    [2130701434] [NAME: aaa] [VALUE: aaa] [EXPIRE: 1 second] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701434] [NAME: bbb] [VALUE: bbb] [EXPIRE: 2 minute] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701434] [NAME: ccc] [VALUE: ccc] [EXPIRE: 3 hours] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]

    [2130701435] [NAME: aaa] [VALUE: aaa] [EXPIRE: 1 second] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701435] [NAME: bbb] [VALUE: bbb] [EXPIRE: 2 minute] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]
    [2130701435] [NAME: ccc] [VALUE: ccc] [EXPIRE: 3 hours] [CREATED: Y:m:d H:i:s]';

if(preg_match_all('~\G\s*\[(\d+)]|\s*\[([A-Z]+):\s*(.*?)]~', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    //var_export($matches);
    foreach ($matches as $item) {
        if (!isset($item[2])) {
            $id = $item[1];
        } else {
            $result[$id][$item[2]][] = $item[3];
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2130701433 => 
  array (
    'NAME' => 
    array (
      0 => 'aaa',
      1 => 'bbb',
      2 => 'ccc',
    ),
    'VALUE' => 
    array (
      0 => 'aaa',
      1 => 'bbb',
      2 => 'ccc',
    ),
    'EXPIRE' => 
    array (
      0 => '1 second',
      1 => '2 minute',
      2 => '3 hours',
    ),
    'CREATED' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
      1 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
      2 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
    ),
  ),
  2130701434 => 
  array (
    'NAME' => 
    array (
      0 => 'aaa',
      1 => 'bbb',
      2 => 'ccc',
    ),
    'VALUE' => 
    array (
      0 => 'aaa',
      1 => 'bbb',
      2 => 'ccc',
    ),
    'EXPIRE' => 
    array (
      0 => '1 second',
      1 => '2 minute',
      2 => '3 hours',
    ),
    'CREATED' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
      1 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
      2 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
    ),
  ),
  2130701435 => 
  array (
    'NAME' => 
    array (
      0 => 'aaa',
      1 => 'bbb',
      2 => 'ccc',
    ),
    'VALUE' => 
    array (
      0 => 'aaa',
      1 => 'bbb',
      2 => 'ccc',
    ),
    'EXPIRE' => 
    array (
      0 => '1 second',
      1 => '2 minute',
      2 => '3 hours',
    ),
    'CREATED' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
      1 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
      2 => 'Y:m:d H:i:s',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: WOW! That's exactly what I meant! Big thanks @mickmackusa

Comment: You are welcome.  I think I may have impressed myself a little with this one.  Pretty elegant.